# Are Android's DisplayMetrics xdpi and ydpi always equal?

Tags: android

I've been checking the output of the DisplayMetrics 'xdpi' and 'ydpi' on several emulator screen sizes (WVGA & HVGA) and I notice that these values are always equal i.e. metrics.xdpi == metrics.ydpi.

I just wanted to confirm this with folks here? Is it true on any phone the metrics.xdpi will always be equal to the metrics.ydpi value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems, no. For my Samsung Galaxy S (GT-I9000) they are the following (reported by Android):

```
metrics.xdpi=234.46153
metrics.ydpi=236.27907
```

Comment: Hmmm... I was looking at Androids AccelerometerPlay example where they display a ball on the screen with the following calculation DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();           getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
mMetersToPixelsX = mXDpi / 0.0254f;
mMetersToPixelsY = mYDpi / 0.0254f;  And cant figure out how this will give a circular ball on screen if they are not the same?

Comment: Hmmm.. can't seem to be able to format the above code correctly:(

Comment: What is a problem? They scaled bitmap using different scale factors for each axis based on different `mMetersToPixelsX` and `mMetersToPixelsY` calculated before.

Comment: Well as I mentioned in my first post, the emulators that I tried it on it always returned the same value for xdpi and ydpi so I thought using them both was redundant. Is there some config that needs to be changed to get these to work more closely like real devices?

Comment: It seems for emulator it's impossible to specify `xdpi` and `ydpi` separately. At least I have not found such parameters.

Comment: On emulator both xdpi and ydpi are the same. When I used them on my Nexus 7 they gave me values: 195.4 for xdpi and 200.7 for ydpi which in turn both should be 213